# Can i update my commands( like awk,sed) to the latest release in solaris?

Tags: shell-script, awk, solaris

```
 bash-3.00# awk '{print NR}' f1.txt
 1
 2
 3
 4
```

but FNR does not print anything.

```
awk '{print FNR}' f1.txt
```

the above line does not gives me any output,seems that the awk that i am having 
in my sun os does not have FNR variable.
so can i do something about it to standardize it.
also, can i get a library of all latest commands and install/update my current commands like sed,sort etc.

**SunOS unknown 5.10 Generic_142910-17 i86pc i386 i86pc**

Comment: On Solaris, don't ever try using `awk`.  It's terrible.  Always use `nawk`, which is also installed by default.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is not just one `awk` and several releases of it. There are many awk implementations which each have several versions. All Unices have their own toolset which they maintain in-house and the software that ships with one Unix and that  make use of those tools generally rely on those being the exact version of that very implementation.

If you start replacing `/usr/bin/awk` with the GNU awk as can be downloaded from http://gnu.org, then you'll run into problems.

Some Unices do package alternative or Free Software versions of some of the standard utilities. Generally, they do that by installing them in a different location (`/opt/gnu` for instance for GNU tools) or under a different name (`gawk` for GNU awk). If not you can download them as source and build them and install them in a different location or under a different name manually yourself.

Having said that, Solaris is known to have very old and non-standard versions of some utilities in `/usr/bin` and keep the modern/standard versions in another place.

That's the case of awk. `/usr/bin/awk` on Solaris is based on the original awk from 1979. awk was rewritten circa 1988 and called `nawk`. All modern `awk` implementations are based on that `nawk` (as that's what the POSIX `awk` specification is based on).

On Solaris, if you update your `$PATH` to put yourself in a standard/POSIX environment (which generally involves **putting `/usr/xpg4/bin` and/or  `/usr/xpg6/bin` at the start of `$PATH`**), then `awk` will be the standard one. Alternatively, you can call `nawk` instead of `awk`.

That's the same for `sh`, you can use `/usr/xpg4/bin/sh` or `ksh`.

In a standard sh (that is, **not** `/bin/sh` on Solaris), you can also use

```
 command -p awk
```

To be sure to call the *portable* awk instead of the old one.

Comment: Or you can use `PATH=$(getconf PATH) awk` to get the new awk compliant with POSIX instead of the old one.